# How to change location of tick labels of artist_axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I [draw](http:////gist.github.com/4efa89df3fa083fce45eee1451158282) a unit circle:
[image]

Due to the intersection of the circle and the axes, xticks and yticks labels are invisible. How can I place these tick labels to nearby places while keeping previous labels?

Comment: Maybe you first want to read existing questions and answers, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615887/how-to-move-a-ticks-label-in-matplotlib) and show in how far they don't help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add text to the figure using `plt.axis(x,y,'text')` to effectively position tick labels wherever you want:

```
# Remove tick labels
ax.set_xticklabels('')
ax.set_yticklabels('')

# Add more visible tick labels with a slight offset
plt.text(0.05,0.05,'0')
plt.text(1.05,0.05,'1')
plt.text(0.05,1.05,'1')
plt.text(-0.95,0.05,'-1')
plt.text(0.05,-0.95,'-1')
```

[image: Plot with offset labels]